# How to convert multi-page tiff to jpeg, using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, jpeg, tiff

I am trying to batch process images, in which I need to convert some multi-page tiff files to individual jpeg images, I tried with PIL library of Python but sadly PIL only supports conversion of a single page, in this case the first page in TIFF files.